# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas

`originalEstimateSeconds` is a key in `timetracking` dict and returns an integer. I want to access that integer and append to the StoryEstimate list. For index 0 and 1, it works (according to the debugger). But for index 3, timetracking contains and empty dict which is fine, that's why the check is there. However, PyCharm still returns the

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.
```

`endResult` and `df` are pandas dataframes.

StoryEstimate is

```
  StoryEstimate = []
  for i, r in endResult.iterrows():
    timetracking = endResult['issues'][i]['fields']['timetracking']
    if 'originalEstimateSeconds' in timetracking:
      StoryEstimate.append(estimate)
  df['Story Actual Hrs'] = StoryEstimate
```

Comment: What is the shape of 'estimate' when it gets added to 'df'?

Comment: I edited the code I posted because there were some errors. Still the same error when pycharm returns. StoryEstimate is a list that is then put into the dataframe column called 'Story Actual Hrs'. Should be 1x3 column

Comment: The indentation seems wrong.

Comment: fixed (code was indented correctly in pycharm)\